# How to make this neural network traning function faster

Tags: c#, multithreading, neural-network

variable input is a jagged array, i.e. 90 x 600.

ideal is also jagged array of 90 x 1

```
BeginTraining()
{
    FeedforwardNetwork network = new FeedforwardNetwork();
    network.AddLayer(new FeedforwardLayer(600));
    network.AddLayer(new FeedforwardLayer(1000));
    network.AddLayer(new FeedforwardLayer(90));
    network.Reset();

    // train the neural network
    Train train = new  HeatonResearchNeural.Feedforward.Train.Backpropagation.Backpropagation(network, input, ideal,
                0.7, 0.9);

    int epoch = 1;

    do
    {
        lblNoEpochs.Text= epoch.ToString();
        lblNoEpochs.Update();
        train.Iteration();
        lblPcError.Text = train.Error.ToString();
        lblPcError.Update();
        epoch++;
    } while((epoch < 5000) && (train.Error > 0.001));

        // test the neural network
        for (int i = 0; i < input.Length; i++)
        {
            //testing code
        }
```

Each epoch s taking at least 5 minutes.

How to reduce this time?

Comment: No,just edited the code, please refresh.

Comment: your `do {` has no closing bracket

Comment: I don't know what the `train.iteration();` does, but if that's a long iteration where lots of code gets executed I can imagine that being the culprit. As that iteration gets executed 5000 times too. (not to mention it's in the code twice)

Comment: reformatted code please refresh.

Comment: input set consist of 90 symbols each of which has 600 double values.Each input set is iterated till 5000 epochs.I don't known much about train().I am using jeff heaton's nn lib for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the real question is - can the do/while be parallel.

as long as I know the training waves depends on each other so the next depends on the results of the previous. hence ordering is absolutely a must.

so I figure the answer is - this cannot be faster.

Answer (score 1):

Well, in my opinion you could:

1. [Run a profiler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3927/what-are-some-good-net-profilers)
2. Find out what is slow
3. Optimize

Repeat as needed.